# How can I add and index attribute to xml elements using XQuery in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xslt, xquery

I have a xml documents stored in an `xml` type column that looks like this

```
<root>
  ...
  <foo>
     ....
  </foo>
  <foo>
     ....
  </foo>
  ...
</root>
```

I want to transform it so that it looks like this

```
<foos>
  <foo id="1">
     ....
  </foo>
  <foo id="2">
     ....
  </foo>
  ....
</foos>
```

Basically I want extract all the foo elements including their contents with each foo having a unique index based on its order in document.

Is there a way to do this using XQuery in SQL Server?

Alternatively, is there a way to run a xsl transform in SQL Server?

I am using SQL Server 2014 Express.

Comment: The xml is the result of a select statement? In SQL Server you can use SELECT * FROM table FOR XML AUTO (e.g.) - there are other options

Comment: The documents stored in a column of type xml in a table. The foo elements have a relatively complex structure which I want to preserve in my result set. Have updated the question accordingly.